# Remapping issue Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Please, bear with me, I'm a autohotkey noob. I want left: control and shift to switch from their current key value to arrow: down and up respectively when pressing the F2 key. And when the F2 key is pressed again, I want left: control and shift to return to their original key value. This is my code so far:

```
F2::
{
    if LShift = Up
    {
        LShift::Send {LShift}   
    }
    else
    {
       LShift::Send {Up}        
    } 
    if LControl = Down
    {
       LControl::Send {LControl}    
    }
   else
   {
      LControl::Send {Down}     
   }    
}
```

Regrettably I haven't been able to make it work. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hotkeys that go over multiple lines don't use curly braces. They
  start with the hotkey label and end with a simple `Return`.
- You can't enclose hotkey labels by normal if statements. You have to use
  special #If statements instead.
- Nesting hotkeys is also definitely not what you want to do.
- To remap a key you can use the single line hotkey syntax.

You can pretty much short your code down to:

```
F2::(F2Toggle:=!F2Toggle)

#If F2Toggle
    LShift::Up
    LControl::Down
#If
```

Pressing F2 will toggle the variable `F2Toggle` between true and false. `#If F2Toggle` means if the variable `F2Toggle` is currently set to True then enable the hotkeys below. `#If` marks the end of the special `#If` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for both the explanation and the code! You made my day :)

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left.